# Function' object has no attribute 'get_sort_key[peewee]

Tags: python, pandas, peewee

Пытаюсь перенести датафрейм в базу dqlite3 с помощью:

```
list_of_dicts = df.reset_index().to_dict(orient='list')
DataModel.insert_many(list_of_dicts).execute()
```

и получаю ошибку: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_sort_key', в чем может быть ошибка, или есть еще метод переноса фрейма в базу. Sqlite3 не предлагать, нужно именно в этой библиотеке.

Полная ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:...\set\1.py", line 14, in <module>
    da.insert_many(list_of_dicts).execute()
  File "*module*\peewee.py", line 1778, in inner
    return method(self, database, *args, **kwargs)
  File "*module*\peewee.py", line 1849, in execute
    return self._execute(database)
  File "*module*\peewee.py", line 2567, in _execute
    return super(Insert, self)._execute(database)
  File "*module*\peewee.py", line 2316, in _execute
    cursor = database.execute(self)
  File "*module*\peewee.py", line 2948, in execute
    sql, params = ctx.sql(query).query()
  File "*module*\peewee.py", line 601, in sql
    return obj.__sql__(self)
  File "*module*\peewee.py", line 2542, in __sql__
    self._simple_insert(ctx)
  File "*module*\peewee.py", line 2416, in _simple_insert
    return self._generate_insert((self._insert,), ctx)
  File "*module*\peewee.py", line 2466, in _generate_insert
    columns = sorted(accum, key=lambda obj: obj.get_sort_key(ctx))
  File "*module*\peewee.py", line 2466, in <lambda>
    columns = sorted(accum, key=lambda obj: obj.get_sort_key(ctx))
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_sort_key'
```

Comment: Покажите **полный** трейс ошибки, место тут бесплатное. Там должно быть написано, на какие именно строки кода оно ругается. Лучше весь трейс ошибки приведите, в виде текста.

Comment: Добавил полную ошибку.

Comment: Так. А вообще `insert_many` какого типа данные ожидает на вход и какого типа данные вы ей передаёте? Проблема явно в этом. Мне кажется оно ожидает список словарей, а у вас получается просто словарь или что-то в этом роде. В общем, проверьте что у вас в `list_of_dicts` и какой тип ожидается.

Comment: Да, я подавал словарь, а нужно подавать лист словарей, спасибо.